# Azure Static Web App using pipeline env variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML task for deploying a static web app:

```
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    name: DeployStaticWebApp
    displayName: Deploy Static Web App
    inputs:
      app_location: 'web-app'
      app_build_command: 'npm ci && npm run build'
      cwd: '${{ parameters.root }}/webapp_package'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
    env:
      REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI: $(REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI)
```

This works fine. Is it possible to create a single pipeline variable containing all these values (REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID, REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID, REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID, REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI) instead of 4 and pass that to ***env***? How would I do that?

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to create a react app hosted as Static WebApp on Azure

Comment: So, what's the need to compress four pipeline variables into one?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing here is storing these in a variable template file. You can have one for each environment if you'd like and just load the variable template at the job like:

```
jobs:
- deployment: '${{ parameters.serviceName }}_${{ parameters.environmentName }}_
  environment: ${{ parameters.environmentName }}
  variables: 
  - template: ../variables/${{parameters.environmentName}}_variables.yml
```

Once this is loaded then you can refer to the variables in the same manner you already are. This will effectively be defining all those values in a separate file which is read in by one line so it would save you some overhead.

Here is more on [variable templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse)